# Exporting Data From MySQL to a Text File in Desired Format

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys i need some help on my project.

****My PHP Code**** --- these code below get specific data from my database and i use 2 tables in join because of normalization. it displays the data i get in the browser for checking and what i want is to save my selected data into text file with specific format. please see other details below.

```html
<?php

$conn = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'db2' );
if ( $conn->connect_errno ) {
  die( "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error );
}

$fp = fopen("result.txt", "w");

$query = "SELECT product_id FROM orders_lines"; //dont mind these
$result = $conn->query($query); //dont mind these

$queryjoin = "SELECT orders_lines.product_id, orders.id FROM orders_lines INNER JOIN orders ON orders_lines.order_id=orders.id ORDER BY orders.id";
$resultjoin = $conn->query($queryjoin);

if ($resultjoin->num_rows > 0) {
   
 echo "order id | item ordered<br>";
    while($row = $resultjoin->fetch_assoc()) {
  
  $string = implode(",", $row);

        echo "data: " . $row["id"] . " | " . $row["product_id"] . "<br>";
  
  fwrite($fp, $string);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

fclose($fp);

$conn->close();

?>
```

**This is the image of the output of my Php Code:** [Output of PHP Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LujtD.png)

**Current Output in my TextFile**  -- 4 is the order_id, 2 is the item ordered belong to 4, 3 is the item ordered also belongs to 4....etc....

```html
4,24,35,15,25,65,56,27,27,48,28,19,49,310,310,610,410,210,810,111,511,411,312,412,512,913,313,213,614,514,214,314,714,414,115,415,415,815,515,115,315,215,616,816,517,417,117,517,817,317,7
```

**My Desired Output in a TextFile**

```html
2,3  //order id 4 -->comment
1,2,6,5  //order id 5
7  //order id 6
2,4  //order id 7
2,1  //order id 8
4,3  //order id 9
3,6,4,2,8,1 //order id 10
5,4,3  //order id 11
4,5,9  //order id 12
3,2,6  //order id 13
.....
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: as far as I can see, you are virtually there - you just need to do some string manipulation so the output is how you want befor you save it to the file

Comment: @kerry, thanks. i tried to do some research but i cant solve it. im not really good at logic.

Comment: I am having trouble with comparing your actual output shown to the desired result and understanding you. '4 is the order_id, 2 is the item ordered belong to 4, 3 is the item ordered also belongs to 4....etc....'  Then I see 4,24,35,15,25,65,56 as actual output and the desired output seems to have no logical relationship

Comment: well, in database table there is a two 4 order_id in a different row. first one has item_ordered '2' and second one has item_ordered '3'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I got it... these is the right answer i was looking for my problem.. my good friend of mine help me..

```html
if ($resultjoin->num_rows > 0) {
   $currentRowId = '';
   $output = '';
 while($row = $resultjoin->fetch_assoc()) {
  if($row["id"]==$currentRowId){
   echo ', '.$row["product_id"];
   $output = $output.', '.$row["product_id"];
  } else if($currentRowId=='') {
   $currentRowId = $row["id"];
   echo $row["product_id"];
   $output = $output . $row["product_id"];
  } else {
   $currentRowId = $row["id"];
   echo '<br>'.$row["product_id"];
   $output = $output . PHP_EOL . $row["product_id"];
  }
    } 
 echo $output;
 fwrite($fp, $output);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```